# How the compiler treat procedure/functions inside procedure/functions

Tags: delphi

Some procedures or functions are written inside another's, like:

```
function Foo: Integer;
var A: String;
    procedure Bar;
    begin
      A := '2';
      //code
    end; 
begin
  A:= '1';
  Bar;
  Result := StrToInt(A);
end;
```

In this example, all the variables declared in the Foo function, can be acessed inside Bar.
How the context is shared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calling scope passes its frame pointer as a hidden parameter to the inner procedure. The inner procedure can then use this hidden pointer to access variables in the outer scope.

Comment: It is implied - that is, the compiler knows. Look at the generated code to see how it really works. If you want to read the theory, the original PASCAL – User Manual and Report (N. Wirth / K. Jensen) has an explanation. You can find a reference to it on the [Pascal Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)).